# Cannot Parse "Verify" Button or Captcha Using Selenium (Python). Also Want to solve the captcha with 2captcha api

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, iframe, linkedin-api, captcha

## I want to solve the captcha so I was thinking of clicking on the "Verify" button and getting the captcha and solving it by using 2captcha api.

HTML Code for HTML Verify Button and Captcha:

```
<div id="app" class="sc-laZMeE fBtQyX">
    <div id="home" class="sc-gKAaRy cTLErv">
        <h2 id="home_children_heading" class="sc-fujyAs vpPfm">Verification</h2>
        <p id="home_children_body" class="sc-pNWdM bPZwbe"> Please solve this puzzle so we know you are a real person
        </p>
        <p tabindex="-1" aria-label=" " id="hiddenReader" class="sc-iqAclL eLatHP"></p><button
            aria-describedby="descriptionVerify" id="home_children_button" class="sc-bdnxRM DRUpX sc-kEqXSa" style=""
            xpath="1">Verify</button>
        <div id="descriptionVerify" class="Home__StyledHiddenAnnouncement-sc-lzg094-0 kfyjkn">Visual challenge.Audio
            challenge is available below. Compatible with screen reader software.</div>
    </div>
    <div id="EnforcementChallenge" class="App__EnforcementChallenge-sc-1h1h1fl-0 kJqmqd"></div>
</div>

</div>
<p class="load-txt" dir="ltr" aria-label="Working, please wait..." tabindex="-1" style="font-size: 16px;">
  Working, please wait...</p>
    </div>
    <div class="upper-ctn">
        <div class="ctn front" id="ctn-1">
            <iframe class="wrapper" id="CaptchaFrame" title="Visual challenge" src="about:blank" horizontalscrolling="no" verticalscrolling="no" scrolling="no">
            </iframe>
        </div>
        <div class="ctn" id="ctn-2">
            <iframe class="wrapper" id="CaptchaFrame2" title="Visual challenge" src="about:blank" horizontalscrolling="no" verticalscrolling="no" scrolling="no">
            </iframe>
        </div>
        <div id="victoryScreen" class="ctn wrapper hide"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="html-verify" class="hidden">
        <p><strong>Please prove you're not a spammer by doing this quick activity!</strong></p>
        <a class="fancy_btn" id="html-verify-btn">
            Verify      </a>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="audio-ctn">
    <div id="audio">
        <div id="audio_error">
                <p></p>
        </div>
                <div id="audio_instruction_ctrl" class="hidden">
            Press CTRL to play again.       </div>
                <span class="audio_noauto_support_info" id="audio_please_download_info" tabindex="-1">
            Please download and listen to the sound, then type what you heard:      </span>
        <span class="audio_info" id="audio_info" tabindex="-1">
            Press Play and type what you hear:      </span>
        <div class="textAlignCenter">
                <button class="fancy_btn audio_btn audio_action_btn" id="audio_play" aria-labelledby="audio_error audio_info audio_instruction_ctrl audio_instruction_button" tabindex="0">
                Play                </button>
        </div>
        <div class="textAlignLeft">
            <label for="audio_response_field" id="audio_response_field_label" class="audio_response">
                Challenge Answer            </label>
            <input class="response_field audio_response" id="audio_response_field" title="Challenge Answer" aria-labelledby="Challenge Answer" type="text" tabindex="0" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" spellcheck="false">
            
        </div>
        <div class="textAlignCenter">
            <button class="fancy_btn audio_btn audio_action_btn" id="audio_submit" tabindex="0">
                Verify          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="textAlignCenter">
            <!-- aria-labelledby will NOT get read out by IE -->
            <button class="fancy_btn audio_action_btn" id="audio_download" aria-labelledby="audio_error audio_please_download_info" tabindex="0">
                Download Sound          </button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="audio-alert-container">
        <div id="audio_commit" class="audio_info_verify_info">
                <p id="audio_commit_text" class="audio_commit_info" tabindex="-1" role="alert" aria-label="Committing your answer. Please wait...">
                    Committing your answer. Please wait...              </p>
        </div>
        <div id="audio_solve" class="audio_info_verify_info">
                <p id="audio_solve_text" class="audio_commit_info" tabindex="-1" role="alert" aria-label="Verification complete! You've proven you're a human. Continue your action.">
                    Verification complete! You've proven you're a human. Continue your action.              </p>
        </div>
        <div id="audio_disabled" class="audio_info_verify_info">
                <p role="alert"></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="timeout_widget" class="hidden">
    <span>
        <p class="title">The connection to a verification server was interrupted. Please <strong>refresh this page</strong> to try again.</p>
    </span>
</div>

<div class="infoCtn">
    <div class="success" alt="Verification challenge has been solved">
        <p class="fc_meta_success_text">
            <b>Verification complete!</b><br>You've proven you're a human.<br>Continue your action.     </p>
    </div>
        <a class="phoneBtn hide" role="button" href="#">
        This isn't working for me   </a>
    <div class="meta_buttons">
                <a class="reloadBtn hide metaTooltipRight" title="Reload Challenge" aria-label="Start over with a different challenge" role="button" href="#">
            <span class="fc_meta_reload_btn"></span>
        </a>
                <a class="audioBtn metaTooltipRight" id="fc_meta_audio_btn" title="Change to an audio challenge" aria-label="Audio challenge" role="button" href="#">
            <span class="fc_meta_audio_btn"></span>
        </a>
                <a class="gameBtn hide metaTooltipRight" id="fc_meta_changeback" title="Change to a visual challenge" aria-label="Change to a visual challenge" role="button" href="#">
            <span class="fc_meta_changeback"></span>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/json" id="langObj">{"footer_phone_mode_on":"This isn't working for me","footer_phone_mode_off":"","audio_alert":"Please enter your answer into the input box.","audio_incorrect":"Incorrect, try again","capped_calling_title":"","audio_please_download_info":"Please download and listen to the sound, then type what you heard:","visual_challenge_frame_title":"Visual challenge","audio_challenge_frame_title":"Audio challenge"}</script>
<script type="text/json" id="fontSizeAdjustments">{"loader":0,"tooltips":0}</script>
<script type="text/json" id="nonce">{"nonce":"6568106df29738.63473433"}</script>

<script nonce="">
var h = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];

function addScript(id, src, integrity) {
    var s = document.createElement('script');
    s.id = id;
    s.src = src;
    s.type = 'text/javascript';
    s.async = false;
    s.onerror = function() { parent.postMessage({ type: 'error', payload: { error: 'FC_SCRIPT_ERROR', source: src } }, '*'); };
    if (integrity) {
        s.integrity = integrity;
        s.crossorigin = 'anonymous';
    }
    h.appendChild(s);
}
</script>
<script nonce="">
addScript('meta-bootstrap-script', 'https://client-api.arkoselabs.com/cdn/fc/js/502db8fb0970dbb836af047e19bdd5b401c2e49d/standard/meta_bootstrap.js', 'sha384-55ldJqwVJRPguonk8hZVLUL3YV+PsVa7VSp/5e2/LC7d9frCqQN8XKs+9afNi0jW');
addScript('fc-general-script', 'https://client-api.arkoselabs.com/cdn/fc/js/502db8fb0970dbb836af047e19bdd5b401c2e49d/standard/fc_general.js', 'sha384-86ERzKhVYlJFP19jAgrHoKlzO8Gt7vW5IP0fhk5Lgym41VKnvdf/TqYVbZAnqjyD');
</script>


<style>.metaTooltipRight:focus::after {font-size: 16px;}</style></body>

<input type="hidden" id="verification-token" name="verification-token" value="583179c4c676a7353.6679933904|r=ap-southeast-1|meta=3|metabgclr=%23ffffff|metaiconclr=%23757575|guitextcolor=%23000000|lang=en|pk=3117BF26-4762-4F5A-8ED9-A85E69209A46|dc=1|at=40|ag=101|cdn_url=https%3A%2F%2Fclient-api.arkoselabs.com%2Fcdn%2Ffc|lurl=https%3A%2F%2Faudio-ap-southeast-1.arkoselabs.com|surl=https%3A%2F%2Fclient-api.arkoselabs.com|smurl=https%3A%2F%2Fclient-api.arkoselabs.com%2Fcdn%2Ffc%2Fassets%2Fstyle-manager">

<input type="hidden" id="FunCaptcha-Token" name="fc-token" value="583179c4c676a7353.6679933904|r=ap-southeast-1|meta=3|metabgclr=%23ffffff|metaiconclr=%23757575|guitextcolor=%23000000|lang=en|pk=3117BF26-4762-4F5A-8ED9-A85E69209A46|dc=1|at=40|ag=101|cdn_url=https%3A%2F%2Fclient-api.arkoselabs.com%2Fcdn%2Ffc|lurl=https%3A%2F%2Faudio-ap-southeast-1.arkoselabs.com|surl=https%3A%2F%2Fclient-api.arkoselabs.com|smurl=https%3A%2F%2Fclient-api.arkoselabs.com%2Fcdn%2Ffc%2Fassets%2Fstyle-manager">

</html>
```

Code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException, NoSuchElementException
import time
import logging
import traceback
import os

logging.basicConfig(filename=os.path.join(os.path.abspath('logs'), 'bot.log'), level=logging.INFO, format='%(asctime)s.%(msecs)03d %(levelname)s %(module)s - %(funcName)s: %(lineno)d - %(message)s', datefmt='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')







try:
    account_email = 'your-email@gmail.com'
    account_password = 'yourpassword'
    phone = 'your phone'
    job_role = 'data scientist dubai'
    # job_role = format_search_text("data scientist")
    # location = "dubai"

    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.maximize_window()
    driver.get("https://www.linkedin.com/")
    # driver.get("https://www.linkedin.com/") 

 # Check if "LinkedIn" is in the title of the loaded page
    # if "LinkedIn" in driver.title: 
    #     print("Page is ready!")
    # else:
    #     raise Exception("Page didn't load properly!")  # Raise an exception if the page doesn't load correctly


    try:
        if WebDriverWait(driver, 100).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="main-content"]/section[1]/img'))):
            print ("Page is ready!")

            sign_in_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 100).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.LINK_TEXT, "Sign in")))
            print ("Login Page!")
            sign_in_button.click()


            email_field = WebDriverWait(driver, 100).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "username")))
            email_field.click()
            email_field.send_keys(account_email)

            password_field = WebDriverWait(driver, 100).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "password")))
            password_field.send_keys(account_password)

            print ("Entering Login Details!")

            password_field.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

            # captcha page 

             # Check if Logged Into Home Page
            captcha_page = WebDriverWait(driver, 100).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="app__container"]/header/div/div/nav/a[1]')))
            print("Entered Captcha Page")


            time.sleep(10)
         
            # Wait for the button to be clickable
            button = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.ID, 'captcha-internal'))
            )
            
            

            # Click the "Verify" button
            # button.click()
            print("Found the Captcha")

            # #verify_button = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'challenge')
            # verify_button = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#home_children_button').click()

            # Switch to the first iframe
            frame1 = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "/html[1]/body[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/button[1]")))
            # frame1 = '//*[@id="fc-iframe-wrap"]'
            # frame1 = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"//iframe[@class='iframe-content' and @id='fc-iframe-wrap']")))
            # driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element(By.ID, "fc-iframe-wrap")[0])

            print("found frame 1")

            # Switch to the second iframe
            frame2 = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//iframe[@id='CaptchaFrame']")))
            driver.switch_to.frame(frame2)

            # Locate and interact with the button inside the second iframe
            button = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@id='home_children_button']")))
            button.click()  # Perform the desired action on the button
       
            print("found it")

            # Once done, you might need to switch back to the default content
            driver.switch_to.default_content()
            
     
        search_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'global-nav-search')))
        search_button.click()
        job_input = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="global-nav-typeahead"]/input')))
        # time.sleep(10)
        job_input.send_keys(job_role)
        job_input.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

        # job_button = driver.find_element('link text', "Jobs")
        job_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="search-reusables__filters-bar"]/ul/li[3]/button')))
        job_button.click()

        # driver.get('https://www.linkedin.com/jobs/search/?f_AL=true&keywords={job_role}&location={location}&geoId=&trk=public_jobs_jobs-search-bar_search-submit&position=1&pageNum=0')



            
    except TimeoutException:
        print ("Loading took too much time!")
        time.sleep(5)




except Exception as error:
    # raise error
    print("Error:",error)
    # print(error)
    logging.error(f"An error occurred: {error}")
    logging.error(traceback.format_exc())
    # return {"Error Message:", error}


finally:
    time.sleep(5)
    driver.quit()
```

> It cannot go beyond "Found the Captcha":

> Terminal Output

:
Page is ready!
Login Page!
[33028:27716:1130/104653.399:ERROR:socket_manager.cc(141)] Failed to resolve address for stun.l.google.com., errorcode: -105
[33028:27716:1130/104654.662:ERROR:socket_manager.cc(141)] Failed to resolve address for stun.l.google.com., errorcode: -105
[33028:27716:1130/104654.662:ERROR:socket_manager.cc(141)] Failed to resolve address for stun.l.google.com., errorcode: -105
Entering Login Details!
Entered Captcha Page
[6772:28388:1130/104659.834:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(192)] [10:46:59.834] USB: usb_service_win.cc:415 Could not read device interface GUIDs: The system cannot find the file specified. (0x2)
Found the Captcha
Loading took too much time!

Code for Captcha Solver which works

```
import requests
from twocaptcha import TwoCaptcha

solver = TwoCaptcha(api_key)

try:
    result = solver.funcaptcha(sitekey='3117BF26-4762-4F5A-8ED9-A85E69209A46',
                               url='https://www.linkedin.com/checkpoint/challenge/funCaptchaInternal',
                               surl='https%3A%2F%2Fclient-api.arkoselabs.com')

except Exception as e:
    print(e)

else:
    print('result: ' + str(result))
```

I want to parse the verify button and click it. Then i want to solve the captcha of linkedin.

Comment: It is a simple robotic process automation task. Looking forward to some solutions